# Difference between launching your html files from desktop vs launching a development local server for your file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I recently started some web-design and when I look for tutorials on youtube I often see people, when checking their code, using some kind of virtual server to upload and then see their page. I was wondering what difference would there be to simply lunch the html file I'm working and see it through my browser? Does it really make a difference to use a local server? and if yes which ways would you recommend to achieve that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just have pure html and css then opening the file in the browser is the exact same as opening it in a server. However, the real difference is with javascript. If you try to make an HTTP request using js to your own site, it will work on a server but will **not** work if you open it as a file. If you want to start a server, python has a [`SimpleHTTPServer` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/simplehttpserver.html), and most code editors have some sort of plugin, like VS Live Server for VS Code.